# Bind to execute command with last argument of previous command

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to create a bind that executes `g++ !$` in the same way that the shell would interpret it if I just typed it.

I tried:

- `bind '"\ee": "g++ !$"'`, but it doesn't execute command (just
  "pastes" it)
- `bind -x '"\ee": "g++ !$"'`, but it doesn't interpret
  the `!$` part correctly

Any way to overcome it without using some custom shell scripts?

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try escaping the bang and/or the dollar like `bind -x '"\ee": "g++ \!\$"'` . Does it work?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind '"\ee": "g++ !$"'` does exactly what you wrote, which is to insert `g++ !$` on the command line. If you want the command to be executed, you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
bind '"\ee": "g++ !$\r"'
```